# IE 7 Wrong align in Menu div and banner div

Tags: internet-explorer, joomla1.5, css-float

First o all Im new coding joomla template and css and I have some problems with IE7, i have a menu module inside a div and a banner rotator inside a div in Safari, Mozilla and chrome they all appear well but in IE7 this divs shifts to the rigth.

you can see at this url:

http://staging.socinterangola.com

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I just put the HTML source of the page into the [W3C markup validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fstaging.socinterangola.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) and came across several problems, one of which may be the answer: You have two elements with the id="menu".

You also have two <title> elements in the head, and an <hr /> before the closing tag of a <ul> when it should be outside, plus a load of images missing the 'alt' attribute.

It is good practice to validate your markup, especially if your going to go to the trouble of declaring the DOCTYPE correctly as you have commendably done.

Comment: Thank you for your message, but i have one question, how do i change generated html by joomla? this is module errors like AJAX Header Rotator or swmenufree module generate bad html? Thanks in advance.